# Bash - syntax in echo

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, echo

When using `/bin/bash`, what is the difference between the following two cases:

- echo $IFS
- echo "$IFS"

I observe different outputs.

Comment: why don't you illustrate the difference

Comment: This is not a good question, because the information you need about quoting and expanding Bash variables, including `IFS`, is all over the Internet (including this site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"$IFS"` will be a single argument. The function of the `""` is that it bounds the spaces in them into a single word, with spaces.

For example, if IFS contains `a__b` (imagine spaces instead of the `_`s), then

`echo "$IFS"` will be after the variable substutition: `echo "a  b"`, thus the `echo` command will get a single argument. Thus, it will print: `a  b`.

While `echo $IFS` will be substituted to `echo a  b`, which will mean, that `echo` gets two arguments: an `a` and a `b`. So, it will print: `a b`.

There are other differences as well, for example if IFS contains an enter, it will be also hidden in the first version, but not in the second.

Comment: I didn't get this part: `echo "$IFS"` will print: `a  b` while `echo "$IFS"` will print `a b` ?

Comment: @Jake I fixed the syntax and elaborated, how is it looking now?

Comment: So with double quotes, a series of spaces is unioned together with adjacent characters and then presented to echo ?

Comment: @Jake No: by default, bash gets a line of characters as the command to execute. It splits this line to induvidual strings. This split doesn't happen between the double quotes. (And, between single quotes, even the variable names won't be substituted after the `$`, so `echo '$IFS'` will print `$IFS`.)

Comment: @peterh Note the difference between `echo $IFS | cat -vet` and `echo "$IFS" | cat -vet`. The tab and newline are ignored in the unquoted variable and the space is null in `echo`'s arguments.